# Is "git ls-remote" a read-only operation?

Tags: git, concurrency, ls-remote

We are planning to use `git ls-remote <repository> [<refs>…]` without any additional parameters concurrently to virtually any other Git operation. I'm looking for a confirmation that `ls-remote` is read-only, so it can't break any other operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a read-only operation.

Nothing in [builtin/ls-remote.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/ls-remote.c) suggests any operation modifying the local repo.

[It sets as transport](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ab4ae2b415c375170309c2b7ace0e4daa8d0215/builtin/ls-remote.c#L119) the [`TRANS_OPT_UPLOADPACK`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ab4ae2b415c375170309c2b7ace0e4daa8d0215/transport.h#L135-L136), which is used also in two other git commands (which don't modify the *remote* repo):

- `git clone` ([`builtin/clone.c:919`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ab4ae2b415c375170309c2b7ace0e4daa8d0215/builtin/clone.c#L919)) and
- `git fetch` ([`builtin/fetch.c:807`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6ab4ae2b415c375170309c2b7ace0e4daa8d0215/builtin/fetch.c#L807))

  ```c
  /* The program to use on the remote side to send a pack */
  #define TRANS_OPT_UPLOADPACK "uploadpack"
  ```

It is asking the remote repo to send packs, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, VonC. I can't see why `clone` or `fetch` would be read-only (they are obviously not!?). However, ls-remote.c actually looks extremely light-weight regarding the local repository. Seems like it only requires to read `.git/config` and that's all.

Comment: @mstrap yes, I meant two other commands which don't modify the *remote* repo.